# Add list of urls to the Qutebrowser’s sqlite3 history

Tags: csv, browser, sqlite, qutebrowser

#### General overview

I have a `history.csv CSV file of urls formated like this:

```
<url>;<title>;2024-03-30T12:00:00;2024-03-30T12:00:00
```

(The *2024-03-30T12:00:00* is the same)

The goal is to get this urls in the history of Qutebrowser who is in sqlite3.

#### What I did

##### Prerequest

First I closed Qutebrowser.

##### Opening the DB

I run:

```bash
sqlite3 ~/.local/share/qutebrowser/history.sqlite
```

##### Adding the new urls

In the sqlite3 shell I did:

```
.mode csv
.separator ';'
.import urls.txt History
```

The things seams good, except just some bad formated lines like:

```
history.csv:11671: unescaped " character
history.csv:11671: unescaped " character
history.csv:11772: expected 4 columns but found 6 - extras ignored
```

##### Verificaton

I verified the changes took place with:

```sql
SELECT * FROM History;
```

And yes, I saw the urls.

##### Closing

Finally  I closed the console with:

```
.quit
```

#### The problem

When I went back to Qutebrowser and try to open some urls to see if it works, so it doesn’t work. The urls seems not imported.

#### The question

What to do to import urls into Qutebrowser’s history? By the way I described or any other way.

### Update

The links I added appear when I activate `:history` command inside Qutebrowser. But did not appear in history completion. So it’s not a question of database.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite doesn't enforce column types, and the time columns in cutebrowser's history SQL are simple integers (probably seconds since epoch). Yours are full strings with ISO-formatted date-times! So, qutebrowser probably can't parse these.

The fact that you seem to have `"` or `;` in your CSV is another indication that you're not pre-processing your data correctly; URLs need to be urlencoded first. The fact that sqlite tells you there's unescaped quotes really is a bad sign, though; usually their parser is somewhat tolerant, and you might really have data that isn't unambiguosly parseable as CSV. Check these lines in a text editor ((neo)vim shouldn't have any problem opening a file with a couple thousand lines).

So, I'm afraid directly importing them through the `sqlite3` "extended" SQL shell won't work. It should be pretty straightforward to throw together a script in a language of your choice; mine here would be python3, because it brings, built-in by default

- the `sqlite3` module, with which you can very easily insert rows into your table,
- `datetime` for date conversions,
- and both the `csv` module for reading CSV files, as well as simple line-read handling. I'd tend to manual parsing here, because you seem to have quotes in unexpected places.

A stub of the program I'd come up with would roughly look like

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime
# Need to install python3-requests:
from requests.utils import requote_uri
import sqlite3
from sys import argv

def parseline(line: str) -> tuple:
    components = line.split(";")
    url = requote_uri(components[0])

    raw_title = components[1]
    if raw_title[0] == '"' and raw_title[-1] == '"':
        raw_title = raw_title[1:-1]
    title = raw_title

    timestamp1 = int(datetime.fromisoformat(components[-2]).timestamp())
    return (url, title, timestamp1, 0)

assert(len(argv) == 3)

with sqlite3.Connection(argv[1]) as db:
    handle = db.cursor()
    with open(argv[2], "r", encoding="utf-8") as textfile:
        handle.executemany("INSERT INTO History VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", 
            (parseline(line) for line in textfile))
```

Note that the above script is wholly untested, and just written from the top of my head. You can make it executable as `chmod a+x scriptname` and run it from your `.local/share/qutebrowser` directory, with the path to the semicolon-separated file as argument, like `cd ~/.local/share/qutebrowser; ~/bin/scriptname ~/urls.txt`

#### Debuging by Fauve

I could run the following script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime
# Need to install python3-requests:
from requests.utils import requote_uri
import sqlite3
from sys import argv

def parseline(line: str) -> tuple:
    components = line.split(";")
    url = requote_uri(components[0])

    raw_title = components[1]
    if raw_title[0] == '"' and raw_title[-1] == '"':
        raw_title = raw_title[1:-1]
    title = raw_title

    timestamp1 = int(datetime.fromisoformat(components[-2]).timestamp())
    return (url, title, timestamp1, 0)

assert(len(argv) == 3)

with sqlite3.Connection(argv[1]) as db:
    handle = db.cursor()
    with open(argv[2], "r", encoding="utf-8") as textfile:
        handle.executemany("INSERT INTO History VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)", 
            (parseline(line) for line in textfile))
```

With `python3 importHistory.py ~/.local/share/qutebrowser/history.sqlite  history.csv`

In my script you should give the DB path.

Comment: I am debuging youre code right now. But why did you join both url and title? Is the sqlite database of Qutebrowser shaped this way?

Comment: ah sorry, that was an oversight of me; you can see the actual database schema if you run `.schema History` on the `sqlite3` shell. You can also get a few exemplary entries using `SELECT * FROM History LIMIT 20;`.

Comment: And thanks for the bugfixing!

Comment: I debuged the script, and basically, I get the same behaviour. The entries are added to the DB, but from Qutebrowser I have absolutly no completion.

Comment: sad! But then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Their is some news. The links I added appear when I activate `:history` command. But did not appear in history completion. So it’s not a question of database.